# Flutter get list elements from API result with BloC Pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm new at BloC Pattern. I'm sending a request to an weather API and it returns a JSON result like in below.
[As you can see the result is array of json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79yO4.png)

I formatted it to weather model in my response class.

**Weather Model Class**

```
class Weather {
  String date;
  String day;
  String icon;
  String description;
  String status;
  String degree;
  String min;
  String max;
  String night;
  String humidity;

  Weather({this.date, this.day, this.icon, this.description, this.status,
      this.degree, this.min, this.max, this.night, this.humidity});

  Weather.init(this.date, this.day, this.icon);

  factory Weather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Weather(
      date: json['date'] as String,
      day:  json['day'] as String,
      icon: json['icon'] as String,
      description: json['description'] as String,
      status: json['status'] as String,
      degree: json['degree'] as String,
      min: json['min'] as String,
      max: json['max'] as String,
      night: json['night'] as String,
      humidity: json['humidity'] as String,
    );
  }
```

**Response Class**

```
class WeatherResponse {
  bool success;
  String city;
  List<Weather> result;

  WeatherResponse({this.success, this.city, this.result});

  factory WeatherResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var weathersFromJson = json['result'] as List<dynamic>;
    List<Weather> weatherList = List<Weather>();
    weathersFromJson.forEach((element) {
      Weather weather = Weather.fromJson(element);
      weatherList.add(weather);
    });

    return WeatherResponse(
      success: json['success'] as bool,
      city:  json['city'] as String,
      result: weatherList
    );

  }
}
```

**Weather Bloc**

```
enum WeatherEvent { getWeather, getDetails }

class WeatherBloc extends Bloc<WeatherEvent, Weather> {
  WeatherBloc(Weather initialState) : super(initialState);

  @override
  Stream<Weather> mapEventToState(WeatherEvent event) async*{
    switch (event) {
      case WeatherEvent.getWeather:
        WeatherRequest().fetchWeathers().then((weatherResponse) =>
          weatherResponse.result.forEach((element) {
            return element;
          })
        );
        break;

      case WeatherEvent.getDetails:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use yield instead of return element and when data comes I want to send this datas weather list results element to UI.

**UI Bloc Builder**

```
 BlocBuilder<WeatherBloc, Weather>(
            builder: (context, result) {
              print(result.date);
              return (Text(result.date));
            },
          ),
```

Maybe I'm missing something. When I write
`print(result.date);` to my Bloc class it prints. But in the UI class and BlocBuilder there is nothing. When I debug it I see that: after the return element line work it's not jump to the BlocBuilder cause for each is continues. But when it finish it still not jump. Maybe my architecture or approach can be wrong. Also I'm open to suggestions about thats.

So to summarize I can't get "stream result's list element" one by one as stream in bloc builder. Can anyone help?

Comment: as said by @tayomi you should extend your weatherbloc with bloc<WeatherEvent, WeatherState>. Feel free to browse my repo if you need reference to bloc usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not defined a state for your Bloc.
You should create a state

```
class WeatherState
class WeatherLoaded extends WeatherState{
      final Weather weather;
  WeatherLoaded(this.weather);
}
```

Then your Bloc class should look like this WeatherEvent and WeatherState

```
class WeatherBloc extends Bloc<WeatherEvent, WeatherState> {
  WeatherBloc(Weather initialState) : super(initialState);

  @override
  Stream<Weather> mapEventToState(WeatherEvent event) async*{
    switch (event) {
      case WeatherEvent.getWeather:
        // Api call call that returns a weather object.
        final res = await WeatherRequest().fetchWeathers();
        yield WeatherLoaded(res);
        break;

      case WeatherEvent.getDetails:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Next, your Bloc Builder should look like this

```
         BlocBuilder<WeatherBloc, WeatherState>(
            builder: (context, WeatherState state) {
              if(state is WeatherLoaded) {
                return (Text(state.date));
              }
              
            },
          ),
```

You should  rewrite your  API call to return a Weather object

Comment: Thank you for answer and explanation. It worked. Also now I can understand "state logic".

Comment: Glad  it worked for you @burcus. Please consider upvoting the answer so others can find it.